# Exception Handling Application Block - how to replace original message with my own based on some properties of the original message?

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I'm creating a class library which uses aggregated (built-in) COM object. Methods and properties of this COM-object may throws COMException, which ErrorCode property is the HRESULT indicates errors in COM-object's internal logic.

For example, HRESULT (and, therefore, COMException.ErrorCode) = -1001 means that input parameter of a particular method has a bad format.

I want to utilize Exception Handling Application Block in my library and replace COMExceptions with meaningful ErrorCode with my custom Exceptions in the next manner:

*COMException.ErrorCode = -1001 ---> MyLibraryException.ErrorReason = DeviceError.BadFormatOfInputParam && MyLibraryException.InnerException = originalCOMException*, where *DeviceError* is enum & where is definite *DeviceError* memeber for each particular HRESULT from COM-object.

How can I achieve this using Exception Handling Application Block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom exception handler and plug it into the block.

You don't say which version of Entlib you're using. If it's version 5.0 or later, grab the [Enterprise Library Extensibility Hands-on labs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13738). The first exercise in on how to write a custom exception handler.

From there you'll just need to implement your logic to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method, but less desirable, is to throw a new exception as a more standard exception type.

e.g. for a SOAP exception:

```
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException soapEx)
{
    throw new Exception("System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException"
            + Environment.NewLine 
            + soapEx.Detail.InnerText
        , soapEx);
}
```

This is less desirable because you need to catch and rethrow every time you call a COM method, in other words lots of repeating code.

Creating your own exception handler that does the above as @Chris Tavares says is much better. You only need create the excption handler once and you can setup a "COM Method" policy in the EL config that does the handling.